# Why my useState doesn't set default value

Tags: html, css, reactjs, use-state

My code( simplified version):

```
  const handleEdit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (parentLayer === 0) {
      const { content, attachment} = event.target.elements;
      let contentValue = content.value;
      setEditedContent(contentValue);
      let attachmentValue = attachment.files[0];
      if (contentValue !== content) await updateContent(contentValue);
      if (attachmentValue !== undefined && parentLayer === 0) await updateImg(attachmentValue);  
    } else {
      const { content } = event.target.elements;
      let contentValue = content.value;
      setEditedContent(contentValue);
      if (contentValue !== content) await updateContent(contentValue);
    }
  };


const EditForm = (props) => {
  const { content, parentLayer } = props;

  const [editedContent, setEditedContent] = useState(content);

  <div className='discussion'>
    <form className='edit-discussion' onSubmit={handleEdit}>

      {parentLayer === 0
         ?
          // Can update img
          <input type='file' id='files' name='attachment'/>
          <textarea defaultValue={editedContent} required/>
          <button type='submit' value='Submit'>submit</button>
         :
          <textarea defaultValue={editedContent} required/>
          <button type='submit' value='Submit'>submit</button>
   </form>
  </div>


}
```

The thing is , when parentLayer === 0, editedContent is default to {content} which is from props,

If parentLayer > 0, editedContent is empty string,
but i have used console to check out that {content} has the right value.

My question, why the useState can't set default value on the second condition.

My program screenshot for better understanding:

A Reddit like site, sorry for the unfinished interface:

[image]

When editing, you can see only the parent layer has the defaultValue:

[image]

Why React has such behavior?

Updated:
My React program structure:

Mainpage => discussion page => By calculation get parentLayer value  => when parentLayer === 0 render the top discussion block otherwise render the rest discussion block.
Whether top block or the rest block has editform component.

That's to say , the React will render only one page component but many editform subcomponent.

By complete visual design,
Just like Reddit(sorry for the unfinished design):

[image]

Comment: the condition you checking for, doesn't make any sense. Can you explain what r u trying to achieve, when and why u need a default value?

Comment: Why do you have a conditional check in your render if both branches produce the same output?  It's not really clear what you're asking.  Please provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, and explain specifically what behavior you are expecting vs. what you're observing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, my question isn't clear enough, but i may find the reason behind these behavior:

{content} is a prop, and according to
https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-pass-props-to-state-properly-in-react-hooks/

''**useState won't initialize on props change.**''

Every time content from the parent component changes, the editform subcomponent will remain the same state.

What i do to solve my problem(only altered parts):

```
const [editedContent, setEditedContent] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setEditedContent(content);
  }, [content]);
```

Then the component will re-render every time a new layer is created.

Comment: If this is the solution to your question, please mark it as such using the greyed out checkmark. This will help others if they face similar issues.

Comment: OK, but Stackoverflow said: '' You can accept your own answer tomorrow''